# Recursive parsing and arrays in shell script

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I intend to accept a single argument for my shell script `my_script.sh` and parse the values from it using separators. For example,

```
./my_script.sh a-e,f/b-1/c-5,g/d
```

means my primary separator is `/` and secondary separator is `-` and tertiary separator is `,`. The challenge here is the number of values separated by `,` or `-` is not fixed, but variable. Like in `d`, there is no `-` or `,` at all. I can always parse the values separated by `/` as:

```
IFS='/' read -ra list_l1 <<<$1
```

This way, I get the number of times I need to loop over. But I'm stuck trying a parsing within `list_l1`. Here,

1. I need to see if there is `-` and `,` or if they are there at all.
2. If there is `-` and `,`, get the values after `-` and pass it/them as arguments to another script (eg. for `a` `e,f` will be passed as separate arguments to another script).
3. If there is no `-` and `,`, just run another script without arguments (eg. for `d`, another script is run without any arguments).

How can I get this done?

**UPDATE:**

I managed to figure a way for level one:

```
IFS='/' read -ra list_l1 <<<$1
for i in "${!list_l1[@]}"; do
    list_l2[$i]="${list_l1[$i]//,/$' '}"
    # This section is a pseudocode of what I would like to do:
    get 'type' from first part (before '-' as in example above)
    if type == 'a':
        pass the with parameters after '-' to another .sh script, discarding the separators '-', ','
    elif type == 'b':
        pass the with parameters after '-' to another .sh script, discarding the separators '-', ','
    elif type == 'c':
        pass the with parameters after '-' to another .sh script, discarding the separators '-', ','
    elif type == 'd':
        pass the with parameters after '-' to another .sh script, discarding the separators '-', ','
    # This section is a pseudocode of what I would like to do:
done
```

Comment: What did you mean by recursive parsing here?

Comment: Meaning parsing within a string using multiple separators. Is it misguiding?

Comment: Please add the following:  starting from your sample argument (a-e,f/b-1/c-5,g/d), show in sequence, each cut you want to do.  Ex. first by `/`.  So it becomes (a-e,f) (b-1) (c-5,g) (d).  Then what goes in list_l1, list_l2, list_l3 based on these cuts.  Besides that, you know you would simplify your life a lot by using the same argument patterns every other script / application uses in bash ?

Comment: @Nic3500 I have added a pseudocode in what I think would be the section of next level of parsing.

Comment: Check my answer below, you could look on keys (`${!list_l2[@]}`).  This pseudocode does not indicate what is to be done with the '-' and ',' separators you talked about.

Comment: @Nic3500 The separators `-` and `,` are just there to differentiate between parameters. The ones before `-` would be used in an `if` condition and the ones after `-` will be used within the condition as parameters. Have updated the post.

Comment: The rules for what goes into which list are unclear (as you can see from the comments, I am not the only one). Take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @PesaThe I have updated the post, regret the inconvenience due to the ambiguity there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

f() { printf 'I am called with %d arguments: %s\n' "$#" "$*"; }

param='a-e,f/b-1/c-5,g/d'

IFS=/ read -ra a <<< "$param"
for i in "${a[@]}"; do
    IFS=- read -r _ b <<< "$i"
    IFS=, read -ra c <<< "$b"
    f "${c[@]}"    
done
```

```
$ ./script
I am called with 2 arguments: e f
I am called with 1 arguments: 1
I am called with 2 arguments: 5 g
I am called with 0 arguments:
```

Comment: This is something similar to what I had in my mind but I could see that it is passing the arguments `e`, `f` as a single string to the other script, while I want them in an array and pass as `./another_script.sh e f`. When I check the number of arguments received in `another_script.sh` it shows 1 instead of 2. Is it not possible to pass as `./another_script.sh c[0] c[1]` instead of `$*`?

Comment: @skrowten_hermit Hm, not sure I understand. But I used `"$*"` just to print all passed arguments (demonstration purposes), you can use `"$@"` instead, or `$1` etc.

Comment: I understand that. Is `./another_script.sh "${c[@]}"` a valid fool-proof way to pass arguments?

Comment: @skrowten_hermit Yep. `"$@"` correctly expands to **separate** words, equivalent to: `"$1" "$2"` etc ;)

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I understood of your question, I produced this code:
** Edit no1, calling another script using that array**

```
#!/bin/bash

arg='a-e,f/b-1/c-5,g/d'

# Cuts it in [a-e,f] [b-1] [c5,g] [d]
IFS='//' read -ra list_l1 <<<$arg

echo "First cut on /."
echo "Content of list_l1"
for K in "${!list_l1[@]}"
do
    echo "list_l1[$K]: ${list_l1[$K]}"
done
echo ""

declare -A list_l2
echo "Then loop, cut on '-' and replace ',' by ' '."
for onearg in ${list_l1[@]}
do
    IFS='-' read part1 part2 <<<$onearg

    list_l2[$part1]=$(echo $part2 | tr ',' ' ')
done

echo "Content of list_l2:"
for K in "${!list_l2[@]}"
do
    echo "list_l2[$K]: ${list_l2[$K]}"
done

# Calling another script using these values
echo ""
for K in "${!list_l2[@]}"
do
    echo "./another_script.sh ${list_l2[$K]}"
done
```

Which gives the following output:

```
$ ./t.bash 
First cut on /.
Content of list_l1
list_l1[0]: a-e,f
list_l1[1]: b-1
list_l1[2]: c-5,g
list_l1[3]: d

Then loop, cut on '-' and replace ',' by ' '.
Content of list_l2:
list_l2[a]: e f
list_l2[b]: 1
list_l2[c]: 5 g
list_l2[d]: 

./another_script.sh e f
./another_script.sh 1
./another_script.sh 5 g
./another_script.sh
```

Some details:

- The first step is to cut on '/'.  This creates list_l1.
- All elements in list_l1 start with ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', ...].  The first letter of each element after the cut on '/'.
- Then each of these is cut a second time on '-'.
- The first part of that cut (left of the '-') becomes key.
- The second part of that cut (right of the '-') becomes the value.
- list_l2 is created as an associative array, using the key and value that were just calculated.

This way list_l2 contains everything you need, without having to reference list_l1 at all later.  If you need the list of keys, use `${!list_l2[@]}`.  If you need the list of values, use `${list_l2[@]}`.

Let me know if that meets your requirement.

Comment: I'm sorry to have made it ambiguous. The values `e`, `f` are not part of the same string. I need them as separate values. Here, I can see that your solution is concatenating them.

Comment: And how would you separate them?  What would be the acceptable content of list_l2?

Comment: I would basically like `e` and `f`to be stored in an array and be passing them as argument to another script say, `exec ./another_script.sh ${parameter[i]}` based on the `type` in pseudocode.

Comment: So list_l2 = [e] [f] [1] [5] [g], without a,b,c,d keys?

Comment: Yes. When the outer for loop I wrote loops over array elements split according to the separator `/`, within that loop I need to check what is before and after `-` in that particular array element and based on that, I need to pass them as (multiple or single or no) arguments to `another_script.sh`.

Comment: Ok so look at my answer for a way to do that.